# How to check if two indexed arrays have same values even if the order is not same in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to compare two indexed arrays as such that values will be same for two arrays but order may differ, for example i tried doing this but it simply doesn't work.

Example 1 :

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(1,2,3,5,4);
echo ($a == $b) ? 'Match Found' : 'No Match Found';
//Returns No Match Found
```

Example 2 : (tried sorting the array but it doesn't sort)

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$a = sort($a);
$b = array(1,2,3,5,4);
$b = sort($b);
echo ($a === $b) ? 'Match Found' : 'No Match Found';
//Returns Match Found
```

above example returns match Found and that is because `sort()` returns 1 if i try sorting indexed array, and both `$a` and `$b` contains `1` after sorting resulting in condition being true which is totally wrong, this trick does not seems to work either, i tried with many different sorting function like `asort()`, `arsort()` etc, but none seems to work.

what is the workaround for this?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing the return values of `sort`, why don't you just compare the arrays after they have been sorted?

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
sort($a);
$b = array(1,2,3,5,4);
sort($b);
echo ($a == $b) ? 'Match Found' : 'No Match Found';
```

If the arrays have different keys but the same values, they will still count as equal.  You must also compare the array keys if this is an issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(1,3,2,5,3,4);


if(count($a) == count($b) && count(array_diff($a, $b)) == 0){
    echo "A";
}
```

Need to do a length check or the two arrays above would come out the same.

edit:  better solution.