# php checking if 2 arrays contain the same values but a different order

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a quick way in php to check if 2 arrays contain the same items while the order can be different.

This works for integer arrays [How to check if two indexed arrays have same values even if the order is not same in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881049/how-to-check-if-two-indexed-arrays-have-same-values-even-if-the-order-is-not-sam)

```
//these must be considered equal
array(1,2,3);
array(2,1,3);
array(3,1,2);

//However it must also be possible for strings
array("foo", "bar");
array("bar", "foo");
```

Comment: `array_values` function will give you just the values, sequentially indexed.  Apply it to both arrays and use the same comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty nice solution myself.

```
$ar1 = array("hello","world","foo");//equals
$ar2 = array("world","foo","hello");//equals
$ar3 = array("hello","world","bar");//not equal

$ar4 = array();
//Add all items to a single array
$ar4 = array_merge($ar1, $ar2);//equal 
//OR
$ar4 = array_merge($ar1, $ar3);//not equal
//Remove all duplicates
//$ar4 = array_unique($ar4); edited due to comment below
$ar4 = array_flip($ar4);
//if you want to user $ar4 later flip it again, its still faster than unique
$ar4 = array_flip($ar4);

$c1 = count($ar1);// = 3
$c4 = count($ar4);// = 3 when the arrays were equal and is > 3 if not

if($c1 === $c4){ //CODE }
```

So for short this is

```
$ar1 = array("hello","world","foo");
$ar2 = array("world","foo","hello");
$ar4 = array_merge($ar1, $ar2);
//$ar4 = array_unique($ar4); edited due to comment below
$ar4 = array_flip($ar4); 
if(count($ar1) === count($ar4)){ //code }
```

Comment: Use `array_flip` instead of `array_unique` and it will be an order of magnitude faster but otherwise give the same result as your code.

Answer (score 1):

use this

1. Sort both the array

   ```
   sort($arr1);
   sort($arr2);
   ```
2. Compare both by converting them to string - any of the following way.

   ```
   echo (implode(" ", $arr1) == implode(" ",$arr2))? "true":"false";
   /* or */
   echo (print_r($arr1,true) == print_r($arr2,true))? "true":"false";
   ```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$is_equal = (count($arr1)==count($arr2)) && !count(array_diff($arr1, $arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort arrays and then compare them:

```php
function arrays_are_equal($arr1, $arr2) {
    sort($arr1);
    sort($arr2);

    return $arr1 == $arr2;
}

$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$arr2 = [2, 3, 1, 4];

arrays_are_equal($arr1, $arr2); // true
```